# How should a generator be used in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I try to make a simple python function to locate the increase and decrease points of a function (in linear algebra). Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np

from pytest import approx


def gen_inc_dec_point(y_data: np.ndarray):
    i_start = 0
    i_stop = 0
    it = np.nditer(y_data)
    it2 = np.nditer(y_data)
    y_start = next(it2)
    y_stop = next(it)
    y = next(it2)

    # flag 1 means y values of the function is increasing
    # flag 0 indicate that there is no change in the values of y (constant)
    # flag -1 indicate the y values is decreasing
    flag = 0

    while True:
        try:
            if y_start == approx(y):
                flag = 0
                while y_stop == approx(y):
                    y_stop = next(it)
                    y = next(it2)
                    i_stop += 1
                yield [i_start, i_stop, flag]
                y_start = np.copy(y_stop)
                i_start = i_stop
                
            elif y_start < y:
                flag = 1
                while y_stop < y:
                    y_stop = next(it)
                    y = next(it2)
                    i_stop += 1
                yield [i_start, i_stop, flag]
                y_start = np.copy(y_stop)
                i_start = i_stop

            else:
                flag = -1
                while y_stop > y:
                    y_stop = next(it)
                    y = next(it2)
                    i_stop += 1
                yield [i_start, i_stop, flag]
                y_start = np.copy(y_stop)
                i_start = i_stop

        except StopIteration:
            yield [i_start, i_stop, flag]
            break
```

I've tried a couple of tests with pytest and it work the way I want to. But then I decided to refactor it (There are few code repetitions). It was like this:

```
import numpy as np

from pytest import approx


def gen_inc_dec_point(y_data: np.ndarray):
    i_start = 0
    i_stop = 0
    it = np.nditer(y_data)
    it2 = np.nditer(y_data)
    y_start = next(it)
    y_stop = next(it2)
    y = next(it2)

    # flag 1 means y values of the function is increasing
    # flag 0 indicate that there is no change in the values of y (constant)
    # flag -1 indicate the y values is decreasing
    flag = 0

    def advance_it(f_test):
        nonlocal i_start, i_stop, it, it2, y_start, y_stop, y, flag
        while f_test(y_stop, y):
            y_stop = next(it)
            y = next(it2)
            i_stop += 1
        yield [i_start, i_stop, flag]
        y_start = np.copy(y_stop)
        i_start = i_stop

    while True:
        try:
            if y_start == approx(y):
                flag = 0
                advance_it(lambda a, b: a == approx(b))
                
            elif y_start < y:
                flag = 1
                advance_it(lambda a, b: a < b)

            else:
                flag = -1
                advance_it(lambda a, b: a > b)

        except StopIteration:
            yield [i_start, i_stop, flag]
            break
```

But it did not work. There was an infinite loop because the variables declared in nonlocal seem never been updated. Can you guys help me figure out what went wrong with my code?

Here are some test data in case you guys decided to test.
(From Stewart, J., Redlin, L., & Watson, S. (2016). Algebra and Trygonometry Fourth Edition. Cengage Learning. Page 209-211)

```
def gen_data():
    x = np.hstack((
        np.linspace(-2.5, -1, endpoint=False),
        np.linspace(-1, 0, endpoint=False),
        np.linspace(0, 2, endpoint=False),
        np.linspace(2, 3.5)
    ))
    fx = 12 * x**2 + 4 * x**3 - 3 * x**4
    return x, fx
```

From the book, it says that the function should increase at x interval (-inf, -1), decrease at x interval (-1, 0), increase at (0, 2) and finally decrease at (2, inf). Using `numpy`, I test with x at range(-2.5, 3.5).
From the x data and y data that have been exported to csv with `pandas`, I observed that that index of x data and y data are:

```
expected_results = [
    [0, 50, 1],
    [50, 100, -1],
    [100, 150, 1],
    [150, 199, -1]]
```

For example `expected_results[0]` indicates that the x increase from `x[0]` to `x[50]`.

Comment: The endless loop is because `advance_it` is never executed. `advance_it` is a generator, so calling it just returns an iterator; nothing is executed until the iterator's `next` method is called (at which point it is executed up to the first `yield`).

Comment: You are right. I have change it and it work. The inner the function should return the result and yield it in the while loop. But it seem I've ask the wrong question. Can I change the title of the question?

Comment: I think its not an endless loop, but rather the execution got hold in the ```advance_it```

Comment: It is certainly an endless loop. As I said, the body of `advance_it` never executed, so none of the `next` calls happened, and so nothing breaks the `while True` loop. You can see that by putting a call to `print` at the start of  `advance_it` and observing that nothing gets printed.

Comment: A couple of quick comments.  `nditer` is not a performance tool, atleast not in the python interface version.  Generators are useful as an alternative to stringing a bunch of list comprehensions together.  `itertools` has some good examples.  With `numpy` we try to avoid iterations, so generators aren't that common.

Comment: Give an example of data that you might call this functiin with.  Functions without context are hard to test, understand, or improve.

Comment: Hi [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj), I already edit my question to add some test data.

Comment: [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj), to avoid iterations should I save the result in a ```list``` return it at once as ```ndarray```? Can you elaborate about how to avoid iterations with ```numpy```.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications about the endless loop [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici).

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment by [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici), I decided to edit my code; and it works. It goes like this:

```
import numpy as np

from pytest import approx


def gen_inc_dec_point(y: np.ndarray):
    i_start = 0
    i_stop = 0
    it = np.nditer(y)
    it2 = np.nditer(y)
    y_start = next(it)
    y_stop = next(it2)
    y = next(it2)

    # flag 1 means y values of the function is increasing
    # flag 0 indicate a y values is constants
    # flag -1 incidcate a y values is decreasing
    flag = 0

    def advance_it(f_test):
        nonlocal i_start, i_stop, y_start, y_stop, y
        while f_test(y_stop, y):
            i_stop += 1
            y_stop = next(it)
            y = next(it2)
        result = [i_start, i_stop, flag]
        y_start = np.copy(y_stop)
        i_start = i_stop
        return result

    while True:
        try:
            if y_start == approx(y):
                flag = 0
                yield advance_it(lambda a, b: a == approx(b))
                
            elif y_start < y:
                flag = 1
                yield advance_it(lambda a, b: a < b)

            else:
                flag = -1
                yield advance_it(lambda a, b: a > b)

        except StopIteration:
            yield [i_start, i_stop, flag]
            break
```

Thanks for the reminder.
By the way `it, it2, flag` seem didn't have to be declared `nonlocal`, because there are no assignment statements happened to them.